# Leaflet remove duplicate marker using setInterval

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working on a Leaflet map and markers.I am getting markers latlng from JSON and showing it correctly.

l used setInterval to refreshing the method for every 5 seconds to updated latlng and old markers should be hidden and shows new postion markers without duplicates . but I tried every options to achieve this but I couldn't.

As you see Image below shows how marker of aircraft is duplicates on map while using setInterval to update position .
   any help please ?

[image]

My code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var markers = {}; // Dictionary to hold your markers in an outer scope.

  //      map initializing   

  var coords = [33, 44]; // the geographic center of our map
  var zoomLevel = 6 // the map scale. 
  var map = L.map('map').setView(coords, zoomLevel);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport-dark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy;',
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(map);

  //     Aircraft data

  setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      timeout: 5000
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

      Object.keys(data)
        .map(key => data[key])
        .map((position) => ({
          lat: position[1],
          lng: position[2],
        })).filter(position =>
          position.lat &&
          position.lng &&).forEach(i => {

            if (!markers[i.lat, i.lng]) {
              // If there is no marker with this id yet, instantiate a new one.
              markers[i.lat, i.lng] = L.marker([i.lat, i.lng]).addTo(map)
            }
            markers[i.lat, i.lng].setLatLng(i.lat, i.lng)
          })
    }, 5000)


  });
```

Comment: I assume you are trying to poll the api to get the current position of the aircraft after every 5000ms and render the position on the map using a marker?

Comment: yes that what i am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the markers to a layergroup and then clear it.

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map)
setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    timeout: 5000
                    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                         fg.clearLayers();
                         markers = {};
                         Object.keys(data)
                            .map(key => data[key])
                            .map((position) => ({
                                    lat: position[1],
                                    lng: position[2],
                            })).filter(position => 
                                      position.lat && 
                                       position.lng &&).forEach(i => {
                            markers[i.lat, i.lng] = L.marker([i.lat, i.lng]).addTo(fg)
                        })
        },5000)
```